# MySQL full text query with exact phrase isn't working

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I have a table:

`CREATE TABLE table1 (aaa TEXT NOT NULL, FULLTEXT INDEX newTable_ix1 (aaa))`

Into which I insert the values `three 01/04/2020` and `three`. Now I want to select all rows which might have `three` but definitely have `01/04/2020`. So `SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE MATCH(aaa) AGAINST ('+"01/04/2020" three' IN BOOLEAN MODE)`. But I get an empty set. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Unable to reproduce mentioned issue http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/956765/1

Comment: Huh, it appears this only happens in MySQL Aurora (on AWS).

Comment: I believe Aurora support full text search